# How to pass value to a function in javascript (googleMap)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am following https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions
so far the map calculates the distance between specific points but I need it to receive different values and calculate the distance based on those values, I can use the select tag to do it as following but I need it to be done automatically so when user opens up the page the values should be sent to functions to calculate the distance. (I tried to pass values to calcRoute function but it does not work)

Another issue is that How I can pass a list (for waypoints part) to the function?

```
  function calcRoute() {
            var travel = document.getElementById("mode").value;   << currently it is done manually
            var origin = document.getElementById("origin").value; << manually
    var request = {
      origin: origin,
      destination: '238 Elizabeth St,Los Angeles, CA',
      waypoints:[{location: "George Street,Los Angeles,CA"}],
      travelMode: travel
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the calcRoute function definition as below.

```
function calcRoute(){
  var travel = document.getElementById("mode").value; 
  var origin = document.getElementById("origin").value;
```

to

```
function calcRoute(x,y){
  if(x && y){
    // your code to process your parameter values
    var travel = x
    var origin = y
  }else{
    // your code to process, if no parameters given (for default functionality)
    var travel = document.getElementById("mode").value;   << currently
    var origin = document.getElementById("origin").value; << manually
  }
```

and try to call, calcRoute function with parameters, when you want to pass different values

Hope it helps :)